# jQuery function not firing after button click, but does for other events

Tags: jquery, html-table, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a HTML table that has draggable rows using the jQuery UI `sortable` function. It  has an index column that displays the row number.

If a user drags a row from the bottom of the table to the top, the value in the row number column updates to display the correct value. This currently works fine.

I would now like to be able to click a button which inserts a row and recalculates the row numbers for all rows in the table.

I have been able to add the row to the top of the table but the row numbers do not update until another event is fired, like dragging a row into a new position or clicking the button again.

See below for my code, any help is greatly appreciated.

**html**

```
<table id="sort" class="grid">
    <thead>
        <tr><th class="index">Index</th><th>Name</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td class="index">1</td><td>Zippy</td></tr>
        <tr><td class="index">2</td><td>George</td></tr>
        <tr><td class="index">3</td><td>Bungle</td></tr>
        <tr><td class="index">4</td><td>Geoffrey</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**jQuery**

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#sort tbody").sortable({
            helper: fixHelperModified,
            stop: updateIndex
        }).disableSelection();

        var fixHelperModified = function (e, tr) {
            var $originals = tr.children();
            var $helper = tr.clone();
            $helper.children().each(function (index) {
                $(this).width($originals.eq(index).width())
            });
            return $helper;
        },
        updateIndex = function (e, ui) {
            $('td.index', ui.item.parent()).each(function (i) {
                $(this).html(i + 1);
            });
        };

        $('#AddRowButton').click(function () {
            var newRow = '<tr><td class="index">1</td><td>New Row</td></tr>';
            $(newRow).insertBefore('table > tbody > tr:first');
            updateIndex;
        });

    });
```

Comment: call the function.. `updateIndex()`

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy thanks for your comment, I've changed it to `updateIndex()` but this returns the following error `Unable to get property 'item' of undefined or null reference` . Is this because `updateIndex()` expects two parameters, `(e,ui)`?

Answer (score 0):

In the function you pass to jQuery's `click` method you aren't invoking the `updateIndex` function - it's missing the pair of parentheses and should be `updateIndex()`

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, I've changed it to `updateIndex()` but this returns the following error `Unable to get property 'item' of undefined or null reference` . Is this because `updateIndex()` expects two parameters, `(e,ui)`?

Comment: Yes. You could pass an empty object as the first argument as it's not used anyway, but the second would need to be an object matching the ui object used by the jQuery ui sortable component